# Can PHP static class variables be defined using functions?

Tags: php, class, static, static-members

Creating a class with variables like this **works fine**:

```
class Example {
    public static $example = array('simple', 'example');
    // ... 
}
```

But, if I use a function, when defining the variable, I get an `unexpected '(', expecting ')'` error:

```
class Example {
    public static $example = explode(' ', 'simple example');
    // ... 
}
```

I tried it without the `static` keyword and still got the same error. Is it possible to use functions, when defining class variables like that? What is the alternative?

Comment: Just make a namespace and put inside of it a global variable .. it will be exactly the same. And you wouldn't be pretending to "do OOP".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array is not really a function, but an <strike>operator</strike> literal, which is why it works. To use a function, just do it with a setter or external to the class:

```
class Example {
    public static $example = null;
    // ... 

    public static function setE($val) {
       self::$example = $val;
    }
}

Example::$example = explode(' ', 'simple example');

// or

Example::setE(explode(' ', 'nudder example'));
```

Comment: Choosing this answer b/c it came with an alternative way to do it. Thx :]

Comment: Sadly, you can't make it final this way, but if you're calling a function on it, it's unlikely you really want it to be anything you compute on the fly anyways.

Answer (score 4):

According to [**the documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) (emphasis mine):

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be
>   initialized **using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed**.
>   So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array
>   (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a
>   function return value, or to an object.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following,

public static $example = new array('simple','example');